# Why isn't this cron job working?

Tags: cron, debugging

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and have created in the the following script inside `/etc/cron.hourly` and made it executable

filename: `remove_old_tmux_resurrect_saves`

```
#! /bin/bash

ls ~/.tmux/resurrect/* -1dtr | head -n -10 | xargs -d '\n' rm -f



$ ls -al ~/.tmux/resurrect/

total 120
drwxrwxr-x 3 admin admin 61440 Nov 22 16:35 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 admin admin  4096 Nov  5 04:02 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 admin admin    38 Nov 22 16:35 last -> tmux_resurrect_2015-11-22T16:35:29.txt
drwxrwxr-x 2 admin admin  4096 Nov 22 16:35 pane_contents
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin admin 11237 Nov 22 16:35 pane_contents.tar.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin admin   692 Nov 22 02:53 tmux_resurrect_2015-11-22T02:53:49.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin admin   692 Nov 22 05:09 tmux_resurrect_2015-11-22T05:09:18.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin admin   692 Nov 22 05:24 tmux_resurrect_2015-11-22T05:24:20.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin admin   692 Nov 22 05:39 tmux_resurrect_2015-11-22T05:39:23.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin admin   795 Nov 22 05:41 tmux_resurrect_2015-11-22T05:41:37.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin admin   795 Nov 22 05:54 tmux_resurrect_2015-11-22T05:54:32.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin admin   795 Nov 22 16:05 tmux_resurrect_2015-11-22T16:05:08.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin admin   943 Nov 22 16:20 tmux_resurrect_2015-11-22T16:20:15.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin admin   795 Nov 22 16:35 tmux_resurrect_2015-11-22T16:35:29.txt
```

When I run it manually it works fine, when I check that cron has accepted it as a job it works fine, i.e.

```
sudo run-parts --test /etc/cron.hourly
```

output

```
/etc/cron.hourly/remove_old_tmux_resurrect_saves
```

#### output of `cat /etc/crontab`

```
$ cat crontab 
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
```

- What *should happen*: the script deletes all files in this directory except the most recent 10
- What *happens* : nothing

Does anyone have any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of `cat /etc/crontab`.

Comment: Try removing the shebang line (Starts with `#!`)

Comment: Ok, I will try - is that the way scripts in `/etc/cron.X` are supposed to be structured - no shebang?

Comment: That's what I've always done.  I have never used shebang lines for bash/sh scripts.  Only ruby and python.

Comment: thanks, I have removed - now will wait to see if it works!

Comment: Give it a try - you can run `date -s 00:59:00` and it will run in one minute

Comment: just make sure that you reset your system time back to what it was when you're done

Comment: @Daniel what makes you think this is a shebang issue and why are you telling OP to change system time? could you please explain?

Comment: I myself don't use shebangs and therefore removing them is a simple debug step.  changing the system time would force the hourly scripts to execute now, so the OP doesn't have to wait.

Comment: But the answer below explains something I shouldn't have missed.

Comment: yes when I tried to force system time with `date -s 00:59:00` shell returned `date: cannot set date: Operation not permitted`

Comment: @user2196728 are you suggesting I move script from `cron.hourly` to somewhere else to achieve the ability to change execution time - with out changing system time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cron.hourly` file `remove_old_tmux_resurrect_saves` is running as user `root` (hence `~` refers to home directory of `root`) and you are searching for files in the home directory of user `admin`.

Replace `~` with the absolute path to the home directory of user `admin`.

Alternately, you can open user `admin`'s crontab by running `crontab -e` as user `admin` and put an entry there.

Also note that parsing `ls` is not a good idea at all and whatever you are doing can be done with other tools easily and you don't even need a script.

Comment: of course - thats embarrassing  I missed that! - will fix and let you know if it was successful!

Comment: @user4668401 No problem..glad i could help :)

Comment: you were right about *parsing `ls` is not a good idea at all* - I submitted a pull request using that expression and it failed testing due to it not working on OSX operating systems.  Do you have any alternatives to use instead of `ls`? I was thinking possibly `printf '%s\n' *` or `find -exec`